# Problema com $_POST

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, banco-de-dados

Bem eu estou aprendendo a programar [php](/questions/tagged/php) e tenho muitas dificuldades em fazer a junção dele com outras linguagem, nesse momento estou fazendo um trabalho e estou com um problema:

Quando eu clico em uma `div` a imagem que está nela vai para outra, na parte lateral do site com o `.appendTo()`, até ai tudo bem. Mas eu preciso que sempre que uma imagem passe para este local chame uma função [php](/questions/tagged/php) onde eu pego informações de um banco de dados. Eu estava tentando fazer isso chamando o [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) dentro da função que copia a imagem. Mas ai eu não consigo atribuir nada ao `$_POST` dentro do [php](/questions/tagged/php)

**Função JavaScript no arquivo** `script.js`

```
   var idRecebido;

   function CopiarDiv(x){

   if(document.getElementById("copia").children.length <1){
   $('#img'+x).appendTo('#copia');
   idRecebido=x;

   }

   else{
   $('#img'+idRecebido).appendTo('#div'+idRecebido);
   $('#img'+x).appendTo('#copia');
   idRecebido=x;

   }

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "index.php",
   data: {id:x}

   });

   };
```

**Página PHP `index.php`**

```
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='estilo.css'>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Projeto Final</title>
    </head>

     <body>             

          <?php 


              include 'Class.php';


              echo '<div class="SUPREMA">';

              for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){

              //Divs da Esquerda


              echo "<div class='alo' id=div".$i." onclick='CopiarDiv(".$i."); '>";
              echo "<img src='passaros/bird_".$i.".png' style='width:250px; height:250px;' id=img".$i.">";
              echo "</div>";

            }

              echo '</div>';

              echo'<div class="info">';

              echo '<div class="alo2" id="copia">';
              echo '</div>';


              echo '</div>';

          ?>

     </body>
     </html>
```

**Função PHP que pega as informações no banco de dados no arquivo `Class.php`:**

```
    <?php

    class Funções{

    function pegarInfo($id){

    $msqlConn= mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'ProjetoFinal');

    $show=mysqli_query($msqlConn,"select nome as 'Nome', nome_c as 'Nome Cientifíco', habitat as 'Habitat', tamanho as 'Tamanho (CM)' from passaros where id=".$id);

    while($coll=mysqli_fetch_row($show)){

    for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_fields($show);$i++){
        echo $coll[$i]." ";
        echo "\n";   
    }

    }
    mysqli_close($msqlConn);
    }

    }

    ?>
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você não deve usar acentuação, por exemplo Funções deve virar Funcoes.

Comment: Cara me explica uma coisa para que você esta concatenando variável sendo que você já esta dentro do php
echo "<div class='alo' id='div$i' onclick='CopiarDiv($i); '>";
echo "<img src='passaros/bird_$i.png' style='width:250px; height:250px;' id="img$i'>";

Comment: Wictor Chaves eu também pensei nisso mas o problema não é esse pois eu consigo chamar normalmente Funções, o problema é o fato de que pra usar da forma que eu quero eu tenho que pegar o valor de idRecebido para usar como parâmetro e não sei como posso fazer isso

Comment: Tulio eu fiz dessa forma pq oq gera as primeiras divs com as imagens é um for e dessa forma eu consigo pegar as imagens pelo padrão de nome e colocar os parâmetros direitinho na função copiarDiv(), foi uma das formas que eu pensei e a que deu mais certo :p